# Material design drawer

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm faced with a little problem.

How to make a drawer already opened when we start the app (like a static menu but with the ability to close it when we press the arrow button)?
We've got this menu:

https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

and the sample how it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: Can you not just trigger a click event in javascript upon load? I'm not sure how these things are developed that much.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I'm guessing this is Java, not javascript.

Comment: @jail4me, please include your code where you setup the drawer in your app...

Comment: @2Dee I might have misunderstood you
Are you talking about this?

Comment: Have you had the time to try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
}
```

Comment: Can you delete this and edit your question instead (if you feel this is still needed, although I believe the issue is in NavigationDrawerFragment as I stated in my answer) ? You should see an edit link below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you're using `NavigationDrawerFragment`, you are probably missing the `mUserLearnedDrawer` property and the associated behaviour. Basically, the idea is to save a property in `SharedPreferences` the first time the drawer is open and check that property everytime `setup()` is called, so you know if you need to open the drawer for the user the first time. Take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/NavigationDrawerFragment.java). I'm copying the `setup()` method here in case the link goes dead :

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter, AvatarLoader avatar,
    User user) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    avatar.bind(userImage, user);
    userName.setText(user.getLogin());

    String name = user.getName();
    if (name != null) {
        userRealName.setText(user.getName());
    } else {
        userRealName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}
```